# AngularJS: Is it a good practice to have multiple functions in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, frontend

I have a controller which has four functions bind to scope. These functions will be called when the user clicks on buttons(using ng-click).

Example:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.myVariable = 0;
    $scope.funcOne = function(){
        // modify $scope.myVariable
        ...
    };
    $scope.funcTwo = function(){
        ...
    }
    // more functions...
});
```

Inside these functions, they contain some logic like modifying scope variables based on user input, so that the scope variable's change can reflect on DOM. (For example: in the above code, myVariable is modified in funcOne, this will reflect on DOM.)

Some online resources indicate that main logic should be contained in service, then inject the service into the controller.

My questions:

- is this a good practice?
- Should the controller contain a lot of logic?
- If the logic should be contained in service, what should be contained in the controller? and how would you do the dependency injection?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a controller having functions in it. The idea is that a controller shouldn't do model-specific logic and should merely glue models to views. It is essentially a mediator between the view and model. Utility classes can handle most of your data-messaging needs, so the controller is really left to do little other than updating UI components and listening to UI events.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion on the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) involved. In general controllers contain View logic and services contain business logic. The question is a broad one and probably off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: *data-massaging